# Unable to sendkeys/click with selenium Java or JavascriptExecutor

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

These are the steps that my code is running.

I start the chromedriver with the secure shell appt - no issues, it launches the browser and appt correctly

```
chromeOptions.addExtensions(new File("src/test/resources/win32/browserprofile/Secure-Shell-App_v0.8.43.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
```

I then navigate using driver get to the chrome URL setup page to send connection data.

```
driver.get("chrome-extension://pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/html/nassh.html");
```

While on this page from the image below, I tried to send keys or click on any of the fields with sendkeys or click and I get the following error.
I have tried multiple ways and im getting the same results: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Here is my code

```
//Webdriver
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='field-description']")).sendKeys("aabb");
driver.findElement(By.id("field-username")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("field-username")).sendKeys("useridval");
driver.findElement(By.id("field-hostname")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("field-hostname")).sendKeys("10.0.0.0");

//JavascriptExecutor 
// This will execute JavaScript in your script
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('field-username').value='migsrcrfuser';");
```

**Question: Is this even possible, I see an id and the id is unique; furthermore, I also tried xpath and received the same result**. Thoughts

[image: Secure shell chrome]
Breift description: Terminal emulator and SSH client.
Secure Shell is an xterm-compatible terminal emulator and stand-alone ssh client for Chrome.  It uses Native-Client to connect directly to ssh servers without the need for external proxies.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell-extension/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your ChromeDriver to 2.37 (the latest) from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

I think that you are using Chrome v65

Comment: Running 2.37, that was my first thought when I encounter this problem. Thanks anyways

Comment: I was facing the same issue, updating the driver solved my problem.

Comment: ChromeDriver 2.37 is where they Fixed an issue with handling iframe on Chrome v66. The release notes https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt has more details

Answer (score 0):

The issue was frame related. I used this code to identified how many frames and then send keys to the correct frame. phew!

```
    int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
    System.out.println(size);

    driver.switchTo().frame(1); // Switching the inner Frame with 1 0 for outer fram
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='field-description']")).sendKeys("9109");
```